# Regular expression to emphasize the matched string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to regular expressions...

I've a search string, and result from querying the database.

in Javascript how can search the string and emphasize or bold it.

let's say

```
q="dolor";
result = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit";
```

the end string should have

```
Lorem ipsum <em>dolor</em> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum <em>dolor</em> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum <em>dolor</em> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a nice simple function that should do the trick, just pass the database string and the substring to this function and it will return a new string with all instances of the substring wrapped in `<em>` tags

```
function emphasize(str, sub) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(sub, 'g'), '<em>' + sub + '</em>'); 
}

var str = "Teenage mutant JavaScript ninja. Loves JavaScript",
    sub = "JavaScript";

emphasize(str, sub);
=> 'Teenage mutant <em>JavaScript</em> ninja. Loves <em>JavaScript</em>'
```

Comment: I've always done regexp because of the "global" flag which allows a change of multiple instances of the matched string. This example would only change the first instance of the matched word so this won't work.

Comment: @josephnvu: `new RegExp(sub, 'g')` puts the global flag on.

Comment: Yeah there you go.  Pwerfect!

Comment: escaping issue I think, if written to document, it's written as &lt;em&gt; can we fix that?

Comment: oh i was about to say.  if mustache, use triple braces {{{ html code here }}}

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var sentence = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"; 
var match = "dolor";
var replace = "<em>"+match+"</em>";
var regexp = new RegExp(match, "gi");
var output = sentence.replace(regexp, replace);
alert(output);
```

[Regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/oR1kK7)
[Javascript demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/Zbjf7/2/)

Comment: can you please utilize q variable instead of hard coding string inside the expression

Comment: @user2727195 sure, 1m

Comment: can you please make it case insensitive,

Comment: @user2727195 check my answer, it's exactly what you need:) If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer, tks!

Comment: forgot to mention, the dolor is value inside variable q, need a parameterized regex

Comment: escaping issues, I'm getting the <b></b> but I think they're written to document as &lt;b&gt; how can we fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a word boundary `\b` around your pattern and then do the replacement.

```
var re = new RegExp("\\b" + q + "\\b", "gi");
result = result.replace(re, "<em>" + q + "</em>");
```

Comment: what's the meaning of boundary?

Comment: The boundary between a word character (\w) and something that is not a word character. So for example `\bdolor\b` would match `dolor` but it wouldn't match `dolor` that is part of another word, for example it wouldn't match `foodolor`

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the string replace command as described in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

`result = result.replace(/(dolor)/g, '<em>$1</em>');`

Comment: seems good but can you replace dolor with q? the variable itself, can't hard code search strings, if then how?

Comment: Note that you can use `$&` to insert the entire match.

Comment: Something like:

`var pattern = new RegExp(q, 'g');
result = result.replace(pattern, '<em>$&</em>');`

but you need to be careful that any special characters are properly escaped (e.g. '*' and '+').  If you just want to replace a literal string you can pass that as the argument to replace as in:

`result = result.replace(simpleStr, '<em>'+simpleStr+'</em>')`

Answer (score 0):

If your search string isn’t a regular expression, you can use `split` and avoid escaping issues:

```
result.split(q).join('<em>' + q + '</em>')
```

`<mark>`, by the way, might be more appropriate.

Case-insensitive is not so simple, but I still wouldn’t use a regular expression:

```
function highlight(text, find) {
    var lowercaseText = text.toLowerCase();
    var lowercaseFind = find.toLowerCase();
    var result = '';
    var lastIndex = 0;
    var i;

    while ((i = lowercaseText.indexOf(lowercaseFind, lastIndex)) !== -1) {
        result +=
            text.substring(lastIndex, i) +
            '<em>' + text.substring(i, i + find.length) + '</em>';

        lastIndex = i + find.length;
    }

    return result + text.substring(lastIndex);
}
```

It lends itself well to working with the DOM, too.

Comment: case insensitive possible?